# How can I narrow a menu in R Shiny based on menu selections?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I would like to narrow the menu options shown to a user based on the menu choices. So if user chooses "cyl" of 4, they then see the checked "4" box and then only have checkboxes available for "gear" that are feasible to choose from based on that filter.
[image: Starting Condition]

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
server = function(input, output) {
  filtered_data <- reactive({ 
    data <- as.data.table(mtcars)
    if (!is.null(input$cyl)) {data <- data[input$cyl == cyl  ]}
    if (!is.null(input$gear)){data <- data[input$gear == gear]}
    return(data)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable(filtered_data())
  output$cyl_choices <- renderUI({
    unique_cyl  <- unique(filtered_data()$cyl)
    unique_gear <- unique(filtered_data()$gear)
    return(tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput("cyl", "Number of cylinders:", unique_cyl),
      checkboxGroupInput("gear", "Gear:", unique_gear)
    )
    )
  }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("cyl_choices")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I find in R Shiny is the menu immediately resets the checkbox for "cyl" to empty.

[edit]

More generically, I want a choice in any box to restrict the remaining boxes to what is left for options. When I make the second choice using code below adapted from suggestion, everything resets.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

data <- as.data.table(mtcars)[, 
                              c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb") := 
                                lapply(.SD, as.integer),
                              .SDcols = c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")]

`%|%` <- function(a, b) {
  if (is.null(a)) b else a
}

menu  <- function(x){
   sort(unique(x))
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  get_cyl <- reactive({
    input$cyl %|% data[, menu(cyl)]
  })
  
  get_gear <- reactive({
    input$gear %|% data[,menu(gear)]
  })
  
  get_carb <- reactive({
    input$carb %|% data[,menu(carb)]
  })
  
  get_cyl_choices <- reactive({
    data[gear %in% get_gear() &
         carb %in% get_carb(),
         unique(cyl)]   
  })

  get_gear_choices <- reactive({
    data[cyl  %in% get_cyl() &
         carb %in% get_carb(),
         unique(gear)]   
  })
  
  get_carb_choices <- reactive({
    data[cyl %in% get_cyl() &
        gear %in% get_gear(), 
         unique(carb)]   
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data[cyl  %in% get_cyl()  & 
         gear %in% get_gear() &
         carb %in% get_carb() 
          ]
  })
  
  observeEvent(get_gear_choices(), {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "gear",
                             choices = get_gear_choices())
  })
  
  observeEvent(get_cyl_choices(), {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "cyl",
                             choices = get_cyl_choices())
  })
  
  observeEvent(get_carb_choices(), {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "carb",
                             choices = get_carb_choices())
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("cyl",  "Cyl:",  data[, menu(cyl)]),
      checkboxGroupInput("gear", "Gear:", data[, menu(gear)]),
      checkboxGroupInput("carb", "Carb:", data[, menu(carb)])
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as soon as `cyl` changes, you re-render the `gear` input, which in turn changes `filtered_data` which again changes your inputs and thus everything is reset.

Having said that, I would separate the two `checkboxGroupInputs` and use `update*` rather then re-rendering (but this a matter of taste, I feel it is "cheaper" to change just an aspect rather then re-rendering the whole input, but I have no benchmarks on that).

To make a long story short, here's a working example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

data <- as.data.table(mtcars)[, 
                              c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb") := 
                                lapply(.SD, as.integer),
                              .SDcols = c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")]

`%|%` <- function(a, b) {
  if (is.null(a)) b else a
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  get_cyl <- reactive({
    input$cyl %|% data[, unique(cyl)]
  })
  
  get_gear_choices <- reactive({
    data[cyl %in% get_cyl(), unique(gear)]   
  })
  
  get_gear <- reactive({
    input$gear %|% get_gear_choices()
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data[cyl %in% get_cyl() & gear %in% get_gear()]
  })
  
  observeEvent(get_gear_choices(), {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "gear",
                             choices = get_gear_choices())
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("cyl", "Number of cylinders:", data[, unique(cyl)]),
      checkboxGroupInput("gear", "Gear:", data[, unique(gear)])
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Gif showing that the gear inputs changes accordingly depending on the selction of the cyl input]

Comment: Thanks -- see more generic solution sought above.

Comment: Well, you will run into racing conditions in this case. You want that A changes when B changes and at the same time you want that B changes when A changes. So when A changes, B will change and then A will change. As you changed the scope of your question, it would be corteous to accept this answer (and upvote) and ask a new question, in case somebody mayfind a solution to the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with these menus for many months, I realized I was unaware of how they worked.  I assumed that the update functions were intended to modify one or more attributes of the existing checkbox object and the rest would remain the same (including the selection). But it seems you have to specify the attributes fully. So what broke my program most recently was neglecting to include the prompt text and the choices and selection.   When I take the generic example above and make sure I include the same prompt text and also specify the selection, things work as intended.  Thanks for the help thothal.  I learned a few things in how you modified the data columns and did the filtering as well!   Here is the working code:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

data <- as.data.table(mtcars)[, 
                              c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb") := 
                                lapply(.SD, as.integer),
                              .SDcols = c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")]

`%|%` <- function(a, b) {
  if (is.null(a)) b else a
}

menu  <- function(x){
   sort(unique(x))
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  get_cyl <- reactive({
    input$cyl %|% data[, menu(cyl)]
  })
  
  get_gear <- reactive({
    input$gear %|% data[,menu(gear)]
  })
  
  get_carb <- reactive({
    input$carb %|% data[,menu(carb)]
  })
  
  get_cyl_choices <- reactive({
    data[gear %in% get_gear() &
         carb %in% get_carb(),
         unique(cyl)]   
  })

  get_gear_choices <- reactive({
    data[cyl  %in% get_cyl() &
         carb %in% get_carb(),
         unique(gear)]   
  })
  
  get_carb_choices <- reactive({
    data[cyl %in% get_cyl() &
        gear %in% get_gear(), 
         unique(carb)]   
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data[cyl  %in% get_cyl()  & 
         gear %in% get_gear() &
         carb %in% get_carb() 
          ]
  })
  
  observeEvent(get_gear_choices(), {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "gear",
                             "Gear:",
                             choices = get_gear_choices(),
                             selected=input$gear)
  })
  
  observeEvent(get_cyl_choices(), {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "cyl",
                             "Cyl",
                             choices = get_cyl_choices(),
                             selected=input$cyc)
  })
  
  observeEvent(get_carb_choices(), {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "carb",
                             "Carb",
                             choices = get_carb_choices(),
                             selected=input$carb)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("cyl",  "Cyl:",  data[, menu(cyl)]),
      checkboxGroupInput("gear", "Gear:", data[, menu(gear)]),
      checkboxGroupInput("carb", "Carb:", data[, menu(carb)])
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```